# Existence and Uniqueness Theorem (ODEs)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Regarding differential equations, is it possible to have a unique solution that does not exist? I know there are certain instances in mathematics where this is possible and is usually considered a trivial case or "trivially true". Because my understanding is, and correct me if I am wrong, that existence means at least one solution and uniqueness means at most one solution.

I can't seem to think of an example (nor find one) where this is the case but maybe someone can help me find one.

EDIT: Roughly speaking, is there a noncontinuous function that whose partial derivative wrt y exists on some rectangle containing y(a) = b?

Comment: Existence means that there is at least one solution whereas uniqueness means that there is one and only one solution, not at most one.

Comment: @KBS No. If uniqueness meant that there is one and only one solution, then "existence" would be useless.

Comment: What about $$dy/dx = f(x, y) = \sqrt{x}$$ with I.C. (-1,0)?  ?_?

Comment: You could do some absurd equations like $y'(x)^2+y(x)^2=-1$, which is smooth enough for uniqueness almost everywhere, but does not have real solutions. Over the complex numbers obviously solutions exist. // Note that for existence of an explicit equation you only need that the right side is continuous, one can even enable piecewise continuous in time. You get problems with existence at some initial points or the rule for the maximal domain for the example $\ddot x+x=-{\rm sign}(\dot x)$.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann, interesting.

Comment: @Nomas That is just not true. Existence means that you have at least one solution. For instance, linear differential autonomous equations have a unique solution and in this case existence is equivalent to uniqueness. This is not true for nonlinear differential equations which can have multiple solutions. For instance, the differential equation $dx/dt=x^{1/3}$ with $x(0)=0$ has two solutions: $x(t)=0$ and $x(t)=(2t/3)^{3/2}$. So, existence here but no uniqueness. Check any book on differential equations.

Comment: @KBS Quoting Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_quantification) "In general, both existence (there exists at least one object) and uniqueness (there exists at most one object) must be proven, in order to conclude that there exists exactly one object satisfying a said condition" Whereas you said "uniqueness means that there is one and only one solution, not at most one. "

Comment: @Nomas Sure, we need to prove first the existence of solutions before proving that it is unique. If we do not know whether there exists at least a solution, how could we possibly prove that it is unique. That would not make much sense to prove a property of an object that may not even exist. Finally, I would suggest to look proper resources on differential equations rather than a general Wikipedia article that does not really deal with such objects. I would suggest to look at any book on differential equations or continuous-time dynamical systems.

Comment: @KBS And I would suggest any book on classical logic.

Comment: @Nomas The definition for "uniqueness" may vary from one field to another, but here we are talking about differential equations. So, the definition we should consider is the one used in this context, which may differ from the one considered in classical logic.

Comment: While there might be some weird function out there for dy/dx = f(x, y) where uniqueness part is satisfied but not existence part of the theorem, I'm starting to think that KBS might be correct (in most cases at least). Most DE textbooks and notes that I've seen often word it in a way where you show existence then uniqueness but if existence fails, then there is nothing more to do. I'm not being very precise here but hopefully what I'm saying makes sense.